# zipp requires Python '>=3.6' but the running Python is 2.7.17

Tags: kivy, apk, kivy-language, buildozer

I'm getting this error while executing the command `buildozer android release`
 while building apk for Kivy app.
I'm using Python 3.7.4 and still it shows the same.

**UPDATED:**

**Command:** `buildozer android debug`

```
# Check configuration tokens
# Ensure build layout
# Check configuration tokens
# Read available permissions from api-versions.xml
# Preparing build
# Check requirements for android
# Run 'dpkg --version'
# Cwd None

Debian 'dpkg' package management program version 1.19.7 (amd64).
This is free software; see the GNU General Public License version 2 or
later for copying conditions. There is NO warranty.

# Search for Git (git)
#  -> found at /usr/bin/git
# Search for Cython (cython)
#  -> found at /home/Reddy/anaconda3/bin/cython
# Search for Java compiler (javac)
#  -> found at /opt/jdk1.8.0_241/bin/javac
# Search for Java keytool (keytool)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/keytool
# Install platform
# Run 'git config --get remote.origin.url'
# Cwd /home/Reddy/Desktop/Sayhomes/An/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android.git
# Run 'git branch -vv'
# Cwd /home/Reddy/Desktop/Sayhomes/An/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
* master b1f6064d [origin/master] Release 2019.10.06 (#1998)
# Run '/usr/bin/python -m pip install -q  \'appdirs\' \'colorama>=0.3.3\' \'jinja2\' \'six\' \'enum34; python_version<"3.4"\' \'sh>=1.10; sys_platform!="nt"\' \'pep517<0.7.0"\' \'pytoml\' \'virtualenv\''                                                                                                                                                   
# Cwd None
```

**ERROR -** *zipp requires Python '>=3.6' but the running Python is 2.7.17
kivy*

````
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     CONDA_PYTHON_EXE = '/home/Reddy/anaconda3/bin/python'
#     XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR = '/var/lib/lightdm/data/Reddy'
#     _JAVA_OPTIONS = '-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on -Dswing.aatext=true'
#     _CE_M = ''
#     XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = 'XFCE'
#     XDG_SESSION_TYPE = 'x11'
#     LOGNAME = 'Reddy'
#     XDG_SEAT = 'seat0'
#     PATH = '/home/Reddy/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/home/Reddy/anaconda3/bin:/home/Reddy/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/home/Reddy/.local/bin/'                                                                                                                                         
#     XDG_VTNR = '7'
#     HOME = '/home/Reddy'
#     DISPLAY = ':0.0'
#     SSH_AGENT_PID = '717'
#     XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP = 'lightdm-xsession'
#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     XDG_SESSION_PATH = '/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0'
#     XAUTHORITY = '/home/Reddy/.Xauthority'
#     LANGUAGE = 'en_IN:en'
#     SESSION_MANAGER = 'local/REDDY:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/686,unix/REDDY:/tmp/.ICE-unix/686'
#     SHLVL = '1'
#     QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME = 'gtk2'
#     CONDA_PREFIX = '/home/Reddy/anaconda3'
#     QT_ACCESSIBILITY = '1'
#     WINDOWID = '0'
#     CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV = 'base'
#     XDG_SESSION_CLASS = 'user'
#     LANG = 'aa_DJ.utf8'
#     _CE_CONDA = ''
#     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR = '/run/user/1001'
#     SSH_AUTH_SOCK = '/tmp/ssh-lPUylxnHwENg/agent.686'
#     CONDA_SHLVL = '1'
#     CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER = '(base) '
#     GDMSESSION = 'lightdm-xsession'
#     XDG_SEAT_PATH = '/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0'
#     COLORFGBG = '15;0'
#     XDG_SESSION_ID = '2'
#     DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1001/bus'
#     _ = '/usr/local/bin/buildozer'
#     DESKTOP_SESSION = 'lightdm-xsession'
#     XDG_CONFIG_DIRS = '/etc/xdg'
#     XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/usr/share/xfce4:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/usr/share'
#     PWD = '/home/Reddy/Desktop/Sayhomes/An'
#     XDG_MENU_PREFIX = 'xfce-'
#     LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'                                                            
#     CONDA_EXE = '/home/Reddy/anaconda3/bin/conda'
#     USER = 'Reddy'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2```
````

This is the error that I get!

Please help me out to clear this!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It doesn't sound like you're using Python 3.7.4. Try uninstalling buildozer and installing again into the python3 environment.

Comment: @inclement I don't have Python 2.7.17. I use only Python 3 version and the current one is 3.7.4. But still I'm getting this error.

Comment: Well, you'll need to give more information, because it's fairly clear that some Python code has good reason to believe you're wrong. Please post the full build log.

Comment: @inclement I have added the screenshot of the error.

Comment: Post the full log, as text not an image.

Comment: @inclement I've updated the query!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried aliasing python:

`alias python=python3`

And this worked for me as I was running it outside virtual env which caused errors and the default python is 2.7 which is standard.